# Wrong bot directory in readme steps

Tags: botframework, sample, azure-language-understanding

In this link: https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/experimental/adaptive-dialog/csharp_dotnetcore/04.core-bot#LUIS-Setup

Under LUIS Setup the fourth step 
Select `botbuilder-samples/experimental/adaptive-dialog/csharp_dotnetcore/13.core-bot/CognitiveModels/CoreBot.luis.json

The directory is wrong. There is no 13.core-bot under this directory. Should be 04.core-bot.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it should be an issue or pull request in a GitHub repository.

Comment: I would recommend opening an issue here https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/issues

Comment: I already did this morning. Thanks!